Elastic Load Balancer Managing Requests Sequentially Instead of Concurrently - Configuration Issues?
I am deploying a Flask application using Gunicorn with Flask-SocketIO on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I’m experiencing issues where my Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) seems to handle incoming requests sequentially instead of managing multiple concurrent requests, despite having multiple instances configured. I’m trying to understand why this is happening and how to resolve it.
Here’s the current setup:

Application Framework: Flask with Flask-SocketIO

Web Server: Gunicorn

Procfile:
web: gunicorn --worker-class geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 --timeout 340 --graceful-timeout 340 application:application


AWS Elastic Beanstalk Configuration:

Environment Type: Load balanced

Min Instances: 1

Max Instances: 3

Instance Types: t3.micro, t3.small

Scaling Metric: NetworkOut

Scaling Cooldown: 360 seconds

Load Balancer Type: Application Load Balancer (ALB)




Problem:
Even with a maximum of 3 instances and the above configuration, it seems that requests are being processed sequentially rather than concurrently. For example, if I send two requests simultaneously, they appear to be handled one after the other instead of in parallel.
What I’ve Tried:
    as per flask socketio documentation


Procfile Configuration:

Due to the limited load balancing algorithm used by gunicorn, it is not possible to use more than one worker process when using this web server. For that reason, all the examples above include the -w 1 option. so i cannot increase -w >1


Elastic Beanstalk Scaling Settings:

Reduced scaling cooldown period from 360 seconds to 120 seconds.

Adjusted scaling metrics to CPUUtilization instead of NetworkOut.




Questions:

Why are my requests being processed sequentially despite having multiple instances? Is there a specific configuration in the Load Balancer or Gunicorn that might be causing this?

Is there an optimal configuration for Gunicorn to handle concurrent requests better, given that WebSocket connections are involved?

Should I consider using an alternative server to handle WebSocket connections and concurrent requests better, such as uWSGI, Daphne, or Hypercorn?

Are there any other settings or configurations I should review to ensure that the Load Balancer distributes requests more effectively across instances?


I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations to resolve this issue. Thank you!

with your first question, you must ensure that the task doesn't have any blocking eventlet such as SQL/ORM query,.... It will block and make your server processes for each requests sequentially

Thank you @TanThien for pointing that out! You’re right; my application performs database operations that might be causing the issue. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM with a SQL database. How can I achieve async behavior in this case?

if you are using sqlachemy, you can try extension sqlalchemy[asyncio]. Your configuration looks good, you dont need to increase worker number more than 1. If you increase it then you have to make sure the workers can get client socket data from each other like using redis
